# Unable to Set Breakpoints in Visual Studio Code for JavaScript ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code

I create ASP.NET applications. I recently changed my work environment from Visual studio to Visual studio Code. I have a problem with setting breakpoint in javascript files. Of course there was no problem in VS, but in VSC I get the message "No symbols have been loaded for this document."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOMRH.png)

I tried modifying launch.json settings